# Навигация по страницам Angular 2

Tags: angular2

Есть index.html  с элементами формы

```
<input #user>
<input #pass>
<button (click)="check">
```

в компоненте App.Component.ts сам метод проверки

```
class AppComponent{

    check(user:string,pass:string){
     тут если тогда
    }

}
```

как с метода вернуть новую страницу, которая откроется после нужного мне условия?

Comment: что значит _с метода вернуть новую страницу, которая откроется после нужного мне условия_? Попробуй словами описать что ты пытаешься сделать

Comment: страница авторизации, если логин и пароль который пользователь ввел валидный тогда уже переходить на новую страницу

Comment: используется ли Router?

Comment: если речь об этом https://metanit.com/web/angular2/7.5.php то я небось не понимаю, у меня не подгружается полностью "голая" страница, которую я создал (true.html)

Comment: у меня как бы страница в страницу выходит, а мне полностью "голую" true.html страницу нужно ), так как на обычных не сингл пейдж сайтах

Comment: хочется типа, если авторизация успешно тогда загружается уже моя нужная труе хтмл страница (сингл пейдж) и уже там основная работа идет

Comment: вот, по примеру выше вышло что то такое http://prntscr.com/ebjs1y но смысл в том, что при нажатии например на О сайте я хочу видеть новую страницу, а не там где надпись Главная написано О сайте

Comment: Вот из трех твоих комментариев - совсем ничего не понятно. Попробуй сформулировать что ты делаешь и что ты хочешь получить и добавить все это в вопрос. Кроме того, если сделаешь [mcve] хотя бы просто с заглушками - будет проще понять, что именно ты хочешь

Comment: Во первых, если я конечно не ошибаюсь, то нельзя делать это с AppComponent. Если можно, то нужно прописать в конструктор зависимость роутера constructor(private _router: Router) {  } и в методе ngOnInit написать что то вроде if(this.check(this.user,this.pass)) this._router.navigate(['home']); а в AppModule RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
    ])

Comment: А если вы хотите страницу отдельную от роутера, то вместо this._router.navigate(['home']); нужно сделать простой переход в js window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";

Comment: да, именно это и нужно window.location.href = 'true.html' )))), мне просто обычный переход на страницу нужен был, а уже потом уже выпендрожи с ангуляром делать.

Извиняюсь что не смог доходчиво объяснить )

Answer (score 1):

Так как Angular - это SPA Фреймворк, то так делать не стоит. Как я понимаю вам нужно не вернуть страницу, а сделать редирект на другую страницу

```
window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
```